# Getting jackson cast exception while trying to start gemfire pulse with spring boot 2

Tags: java, jackson, gemfire, pulse

I have created a Locator application with spring pivotal gemfire. As per documentation I have set the GEODE_HOME while starting  my application. When I am trying to connect from gfsh  command prompt. its trying to deploy pulse from GEODE_HOME and throwing the below error for jackson casting.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module cannot be cast to class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @18a3c727)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:930) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:889) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:356) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1445) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1409) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:822) ~[jetty-server-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:275) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524) ~[jetty-webapp-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72) ~[jetty-util-9.4.25.v20191220.jar:9.4.25.v20191220]
at org.apache.geode.internal.cache.HttpService.addWebApplication(HttpService.java:169) ~[geode-core-9.8.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.geode.management.internal.ManagementAgent.loadWebApplications(ManagementAgent.java:232) ~[geode-core-9.8.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.geode.management.internal.ManagementAgent.startAgent(ManagementAgent.java:127) ~[geode-core-9.8.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.geode.management.internal.SystemManagementService.startManager(SystemManagementService.java:432) ~[geode-core-9.8.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.geode.management.internal.JmxManagerLocator.findJmxManager(JmxManagerLocator.java:102) ~[geode-core-9.8.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.geode.management.internal.JmxManagerLocator.processRequest(JmxManagerLocator.java:52) ~[geode-core-9.8.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.InternalLocator$PrimaryHandler.processRequest(InternalLocator.java:1309) ~[geode-core-9.8.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.tcpserver.TcpServer.processOneConnection(TcpServer.java:475) ~[geode-core-9.8.4.jar:na]
at org.apache.geode.distributed.internal.tcpserver.TcpServer.lambda$processRequest$0(TcpServer.java:369) ~[geode-core-9.8.4.jar:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module cannot be cast to class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @18a3c727)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1152) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module cannot be cast to class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module (com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jdk8.Jdk8Module is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader @18a3c727)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.registerWellKnownModulesIfAvailable(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:740) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.configure(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:607) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:590) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:57) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:66) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:204) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
... 37 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem should be fixed in Geode `1.11.0` and is covered by this Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7334.

Here is some background to the problem and a potential workaround: (references to 'joda' can be replaced by 'jdk8')

When the webapp starts up it loads `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module` (which is an abstract class) using the webapp’s classloader. At some point Spring attempts to load various ObjectMappers [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java#L772-L822](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/809009e6c4d8653ea18e8fe9ae590242871711c4/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java#L772-L822). In this case it finds the joda module on the **system** classpath. In order to resolve the `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule` class (by the system classloader), it also needs to load the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module` which is then **also** loaded by system classloader. However, this means that the `JodaModule` is not compatible with the `c.f.j.d.Module` class loaded by the webapp; resulting in the exception.

As long as all the necessary jackson jars are on the system classpath, a workaround would be to remove all the jackson jars from the webapp jar. For example: `zip -d .../tools/Pulse/geode-pulse-1.10.0.war WEB-INF/lib/jackson\*`

Comment: Thanks a lot @JensD ..it worked with zip -d .../tools/Pulse/geode-pulse-1.10.0.war WEB-INF/lib/jackson\*. As I am using pivotal  gemfire , so I don't have control on the particular maven dependency because they are not using Geode 1.11.0. Pivotal 
 gemfire uses there own internal implementation i.e  io.pivotal.gemfire:geode-core:jar